# How to setup my board to Share Work Item with sub teams?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-boards

How to share a Work Item created in a team with your subteams?

For instance,

I have the follow set up

- Main Team (team)

  - Squad 1 (sub team)
  - Squad 2 (sub team)

So, I create a User Story on the Main team and I would like to be visible also to Squad 1 and 2. Today I can only create a User Story on Squad 1 and I can view on Main team board. However, the same approach considering Main team to sub teams does not work

How to set up this?

Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which iterations and areas are available to the teams (squads) you have set up.

Navigate to Project Settings > Teams, and select Squad 1. At the bottom of the Team Profile panel, select Iterations and areas.

[image]

You'll then want to navigate to Iterations (_settings/work-team?_a=iterations#) and select the iterations this team can see. Once you've selected the appropriate iterations, you can more onto Areas. Repeat for Squad 2, and you should be set.

Comment: Hi Richie! I tried to do this but I'm still see my US. Even set up the interations, the US isn't appear. I set up the Areas and sub-areas to be visible but does not work as well

Comment: Are you a member of both of the squads?

Comment: Yes, I'm. I set up both teams and I was added both as well

Comment: OK, in that case I think you'll need to either have the guys look at the 'Main Team' sprints, or add the users to both Main Team **and** Squad 1/2. This way everyone can see Main Team work items, and then they can see squad-specific items by changing the Team from the Sprints page.